# Consistent header HTML across multiple sites

Tags: web-development, headers

We've got several sites. Some are HTML/Angular, some are built on a CMS, some are built on other code. What we'd like to do is have a consistent header experience for each site. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I've got a couple of options -

1. Have it served on one site - then put it in an iFrame on each of the sites.

   - Advantages here are that we only need to deploy to one place, it'll be always consistent
   - Downsides I can see are that it may not work that well when we have to resize the header responsively, and that I'm not sure if using iframes are considered bad practice now. Also I'm not sure how the links would work with angular routing.
2. Have the HTML/CSS stored in my source control, then have each application pull it in.

   - Advantage/Disadvantage - headers aren't automatically updated across all sites. They have to be deployed individually.
   - Disadvantage - Possible CSS conflicts since its written in isolation?
   - Advantage - Pretty simple solution
3. Some other way?

Comment: hmmmmmmmmm, are they all pulling any common code anywhere? for instance, are all of the websites pulling from some common server? if it's an apache server, you should be able to override some of the config files to allow a common folder for all of your sites. once you have that, you can make a simple html include call on the top of your header files to all reach out to the same html call.

Comment: What do you mean by "...in my source control"?

Comment: Use an image ;)

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of Google Analytics for example. That might give you some ideas to do it with a javascript file.